# How to programmatically add multiple views at the bottom of a layout file without them overlapping

Tags: android

I have successfully added a new view to the bottom of my layout using the resources on Stack Exchange and other. However, if I try to add a second view programmatically, the two views appear to overlap.

This code block successfully adds a new view to my layout file.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout activityMain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        // First view
        View playControlsPanelMinimized = new View(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        final float scale = activityMain.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dps = 10;
        int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
        params.height = pixels;
        playControlsPanelMinimized.setLayoutParams(params);
        playControlsPanelMinimized.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFF"));
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        activityMain.addView(playControlsPanelMinimized);
```

However, when I add a second view by simply repeating the code with new variables, I see there is an overlap behavior, to the effect that I only see the first view.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout activityMain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        // First view
        View playControlsPanelMinimized = new View(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        final float scale = activityMain.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dps = 10;
        int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
        params.height = pixels;
        playControlsPanelMinimized.setLayoutParams(params);
        playControlsPanelMinimized.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFF"));
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        activityMain.addView(playControlsPanelMinimized);

        // Second View
        View playControlsPanelMinimized2 = new View(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        final float scale2 = activityMain.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dps2 = 10;
        int pixels2 = (int) (dps2 * scale2 + 0.5f);
        params2.height = pixels2;
        playControlsPanelMinimized2.setLayoutParams(params2);
        playControlsPanelMinimized2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFF"));
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        activityMain.addView(playControlsPanelMinimized2);
```

**edit:**

I changed `activity_main.xml` to LinearLaout, and adjusted my variables accordingly, but now I no longer see the views.

```
        LinearLayout activityMain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        // First View
        View playControlsPanelMinimized = new View(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        final float scale = activityMain.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dps = 10;
        int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
        params.height = pixels;
        playControlsPanelMinimized.setLayoutParams(params);
        playControlsPanelMinimized.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFF"));
        //params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        activityMain.addView(playControlsPanelMinimized);
```

**edit**

I am trying a new technique with the relative layout method to no avail as of yet

```
View playControlsPanelMinimized = new LinearLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        final float scale = activityMain.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dps = 10;
        int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
        params.height = pixels;
        playControlsPanelMinimized.setLayoutParams(params);
        playControlsPanelMinimized.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFF"));
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        activityMain.addView(playControlsPanelMinimized);

        View A = new View(this);
        View B = new View(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        A.setLayoutParams(params2);
        B.setLayoutParams(params2);

        playControlsPanelMinimized.addView(A);
        playControlsPanelMinimized.addView(B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your RelativeLayout activity_main with LinearLayout which have orientation horizontal or vertical

Comment: See my new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981371/setting-view-object-parameters-height-and-width-crashes-app-with-null-referenc)

Answer (score 0):

- Use lnearLayout instead of Relative layout, may be you need to use **weightsum**
  set **orientation** to vertical / horizontal
- put view right of other view and set it in xml .

Comment: See my new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981371/setting-view-object-parameters-height-and-width-crashes-app-with-null-referenc)