# Setting view object parameters "height and width" crashes app with null reference error

Tags: android

I am trying to add a new view to my linear layout `activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Using this code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create and add new view to activity_main
        LinearLayout activityMain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        View playControlsPanelMinimized = new View(this);
        activityMain.addView(playControlsPanelMinimized);
```

However, When I try to set the height and width

```
    // Set height and width code
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = playControlsPanelMinimized.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 10;
    params.width = 10;
```

With the resulting code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create and add new view to activity_main
        LinearLayout activityMain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        View playControlsPanelMinimized = new View(this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = playControlsPanelMinimized.getLayoutParams();

        // Set height and width code
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = playControlsPanelMinimized.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = 10;
        params.width = 10;

        activityMain.addView(playControlsPanelMinimized);
```

The app crashes on start up, with the following error in the log cat

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ...
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int
 android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.height' on a null object reference
```

In other words, the `params` object is null, and I cannot write to it. I thought this was the correct way to change height and width of a view object.

**edit**

An individual suggested I change height and width accordingly

```
playControlsPanelMinimized.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));
```

Although the app no longer crashes on startup with this method, I do not see the new view.

**edit**

I have added a background color but still I see no view

```
 playControlsPanelMinimized.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFF"));
```

Comment: `getLayoutParams()` "This method may return null if this View is not attached to a parent ViewGroup or setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams) was not invoked successfully."

Comment: Are you saying that I need to add `activityMain.addView(playControlsPanelMinimized);` before I set the paramters?

Comment: I think maybe diyoda's answer could be correct. You can't get the layout params if you haven't set them yet.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but I don't see the view, but at least the app does not crash on startup....

Comment: Maybe the prefix `ViewGroup` has some relation to the problem? `playControlsPanelMinimized.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));`

Comment: I added my `activity_main.xml` to the question... no color is not the problem...

Comment: @the_prole I think you are adding this new view to the activityMain LinearLayout But it has this listView1 ListView, That is taking all the space I think. That may be the reason, Comment out the ListView and see if you get see the color

Comment: @Diyoda I think you might be right, however, the list view is part of my app. I cannot remove it. I am reverting to my original strategy, using the relative layout. Maybe you can answer my [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963027/how-to-programmatically-add-multiple-views-at-the-bottom-of-a-layout-file-withou)

Answer (score 2):

You can try,

```
playControlsPanelMinimized.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(10, 10));
```

instead of

```
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = playControlsPanelMinimized.getLayoutParams();

        // Set height and width code
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = playControlsPanelMinimized.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = 10;
        params.width = 10;
```

You can have aother linear layout and inject your new UI element to that rather than the parent LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Have another linear layout here-->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. The app the does not crash any longer, but I do not see the new view.

Comment: What does the view consist of? Does it have any substance to show? From your code it's just a view with layout params but doesn't have anything to show? Yes, maybe 10x10 is too small.

Comment: @the_prole please make the layout bigger, use 100,100 and see if it changes anyhting?

Comment: @Diyoda Sorry about that. I have the same problem with 100,100.

Comment: @the_prole there is nothing in this programatically generated ui element, I just want to make sure that this new UI in included. Can you change the colors and check. I will look more

Comment: Maybe the prefix `ViewGroup` has some relation to the problem? `playControlsPanelMinimized.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));` Okay, I will change the colors....

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, height);
playControlsPanelMinimized.setLayoutParams(params);
```